# Some text in Windows 10 system programs disappeared after computer froze

Tags: windows-10, freeze, taskbar, user-interface, hung

So I was loading this large page on Google Chrome when my computer froze for a few seconds then unfroze. After it unfroze, some percentage of my task manager text disappeared. The data/time in the taskbar also disappeared, and there was an extra B in the Free Space "MB" text in my resource monitor.

The obvious solution would be to restart my PC, but I cannot do so currently as I have a large amount of unsaveable data which I am still working on.

How do I "refresh" my system without actually restarting it similar to how one reloads a page on a web browser? Restarting the file explorer process did not solve this problem.

Edit: So I woke up today and apparently everything fixed itself automatically. I remember this happening actually about a year ago too when I didn't shut down my computer for a long time. Can ANYONE with the technical know-how explain to me what is happening and how to fix this problem manually if it ever arises again WITHOUT restarting your PC?

Comment: You should save your data ASAP and possibly also write it down, because you could be looking at memory corruption and filesystem corruption often follows.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a way to save the data. As it is—I have a Chrome Incognito window with over 100 tabs each with their own forward/backward history, cookies, localstorage, etc. To add to that, the window has turned completely black due to a GPU crash (https://superuser.com/questions/1757242). Bookmarking it won't due the trick since that won't save history or cookies. No extensions I have found do what I want too.